# Function for counting conditional cell formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I've been looking for solution of my problem.

I have few cells with conditional formatting for example: if >=3 cell turn green, anf if <= 2, cell turn light red.
The cell's value is 0, and with this value the cell is light red formatting.

I want to use function/macro in Excel 2010, which will count how many times must +1 to get green formatting of cell. In this scenario I have cell with value 0, to get green I must +2 (0+1=1 (red formatting-still wrong), 1+1=2(green formatting-ok)).

Greetings,
Michael

Comment: In your example, the answer is obviously 3 - cellValue, so what is your problem? Do you need to access the threshold used by the conditional formatting? Do you need to change the value of the cell to turn it into green?

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(A1<3,3-A1,0)`. If the targets vary from 3, put the target in a cell and substitute `3` in my formula for a reference to that cell and make your conditional formatting look at that cell as well.